# Porting package to NodeJS and having trouble with Buffer.alloc()

Tags: node.js, buffer

I'm porting a game server to NodeJS. The problem is that I'm not familiar at all with packets and building them out. After reading through the NodeJS docs, I *think* that I've structured my response the way that the client expects, but I'm the client doesn't seem to respond well to what my server is sending.

Hoping someone can confirm that it's something in my server response that doesn't match the documentation requirements..

The client expects the following response from the TCP socket:

```
Packet Build
BYTE[1] cmd (0xA8)
BYTE[2] total length of this packet
BYTE[1] System Info Flag (0x5D)
BYTE[2] # of servers

(Repeat as needed for each server)
BYTE[2] server index (0-based)
BYTE[32] server name
BYTE percent full
BYTE timezone
BYTE[4] server IP to ping
```

Here is my NodeJS interpretation of the docs.

```
    /** Build response header */
    const length = 45
    serverResponse = Buffer.alloc(length)
    serverResponse.fill(0xA8, 0)
    serverResponse.fill(Buffer.alloc(2, length), 1)
    // Last fill had a buffer size of 2, so our next offset considers that
    serverResponse.fill(0x5d,3)
    serverResponse.fill(Buffer.alloc(2, 1),4)

    /** Build response server list */
    serverResponse.fill(Buffer.alloc(2, 0),5) /* 2 Bytes (server index, 0-based) */
    // Last fill had a buffer size of 2, so our next offset considers that
    serverResponse.fill(
      Buffer.alloc(32, Buffer.from('Heres your server')),
      7)  /* 32 bytes (Server name) */
    serverResponse.fill(Buffer.alloc(1, 9), 39)  /* 1 Bytes (% Full) */

    /** 
     * Trying -12 - 12 range divided by (60 * 60)).  @see
     * https://github.com/Sphereserver/Source/blob/0be2bc1d2e16659239460495b9819eb8dcfd39ed/src/graysvr/CServRef.cpp#L42
     */
    serverResponse.fill(Buffer.alloc(1, -5 / (60 *60)),40) /* 1 Bytes (Timezone */  
    serverResponse.fill(Buffer.from([0,0,0,0]), 41) /** IP Address */
```

This outputs:

`<Buffer a8 2d 2d 5d 01 00 00 48 65 72 65 73 20 79 6f 75 72 20 73 65 72 76 65 72 48 65 72 65 73 20 79 6f 75 72 20 73 65 72 76 09 00 00 00 00 00>`

**Edit:** I've discovered the following that may help me along.

NodeJS equivalents

```
/**
 * BYTE   8-bit unsigned                          buf.writeUInt8()
 * SBYTE  8-bit signed                            buf.writeInt8()
 * BOOL   8-bit boolean (0x00=False, 0xFF=True)   buf.fill(0x00) || buf.fill(0xFF)
 * CHAR   8-bit single ASCII character            buf.from('Text', 'ascii') - Make 8-bit?
 * UNI    16-bit single unicode character         buf.from('A', 'utf16le') - Correct?
 * SHORT  16-bit signed                           buf.writeInt16BE() - @see https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/9hob2u/buffer_endianness_little_endian_or_big_endian_how/
 * USHORT 16-bit unsigned                         buf.writeUInt16BE() - @see https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/9hob2u/buffer_endianness_little_endian_or_big_endian_how/
 * INT    32-bit signed                           buf.writeInt32BE - @see https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/9hob2u/buffer_endianness_little_endian_or_big_endian_how/
 * UINT   32-bit unsigned                         buf.writeUInt32BE - @see https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/9hob2u/buffer_endianness_little_endian_or_big_endian_how/
 */
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you missing?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Got carried away. Was posting my edit as you commented. :o